# which is best about performance static or object

Tags: java, object, static

i coded like this

```
 import static adminDetails.Provider.*;
 import java.sql.*;
 public class ConnectionProvider {  
    private static Connection con;  
    static{  
        try{  
            Class.forName(DRIVER);  
            con=DriverManager.getConnection(CONNECTION_URL,USERNAME,PASSWORD);  
        }catch(Exception e){}  
    }  

    public static Connection getCon(){  
        return con;  
    }  

}
```

and use this code in another java file with a static method call like this

```
public class AdministrationDetails {
    Connection con=ConnectionProvider.getCon();
    //...
}
```

In java API also they are doing static imports like this. My question is why do we need static method call instead normal object, what is the difference.

Comment: Might be a duplication of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15183295/worklight-performance-of-calling-java-static-method-vs-object-creation

Comment: Why would you want to create objects of ConnectionProvider to get the connection object. Static methods avoid this and hence is more efficient

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Connection` is `static` to prevent recurring creation of connection objects when there is no use of multiple connections due to their stateless-ness.